# How to get IIS Express to serve static content above the root

Tags: iis-express

My home page, which is in my web root, has a relative url that starts with `../../lib/`, so `../..` is above the web root.

When I try to serve my site with IIS Express, I get a 404.

How can I get this to work without moving the resources or changing the urls in the html page?

Comment: what do you expect when you're at root and going two levels up?

Comment: For security reasons such queries won't work.

Comment: @outofmind, see my answer. To answer your question, when I'm debugging using IIS Express, I expect to be able to just make it work so I can debug. So, that is precisely what I did. Thanks.

Comment: @LexLi, but for debugging the limitation can be overcome. See my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a more direct way of doing this, but this is possible by adding the following to the `web.config`.

I noticed the 404 url was as if it was at the root, so the `match url` is at the root. I guess it just ignored the `../..` when interpreting the route.

First I set up a virtual directory on my local IIS to serve up the files above the root. I called it `lib` and pointed it at the content above the root. The actual path shown here is what I needed and just serves as an example.

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Files Above The Root" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="lib/(.*)" />
          <action type="Redirect"  url="http://localhost/lib/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

I'm using IIS Express just for debugging and it bears no relationship to how the site works in production. Coloring outside the lines is OK when it's just for debugging. The site build doesn't depend on this at all, and the config doesn't interfere with the site running in an actual environment because no urls are ever going to match this path.